# apt-get stuck after trying to install a .deb package with dpkg

Tags: apt, dpkg

I tried to install a package after dowloading a .deb file. The command was:

```
dpkg -i minergate-cli-release.deb
```

The package obviously needed to access links that were no longer online, so I got an endless number of timeouts:

```
Setting up minergate-cli (4.05) ...
--2017-12-18 16:04:21--  https://minergate.com/repo/deb/repo-pub.key
Resolving minergate.com (minergate.com)... 136.243.102.167, 88.99.142.163, 94.130.143.162, ...
Connecting to minergate.com (minergate.com)|136.243.102.167|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
```

So I killed it with Ctrl+C. But now whenever I try to install or remove a package with `apt-get`, it goes back to this state of trying to connect to a minergate mirror.

I tried more desperate stuff, but it always ends in `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`.

And this `dpkg --configure -a` resumes the `Connecting to minergate.com` thing.

How do I interrupt the initial `dpkg -i ...` command Any help would be immensly appreciated !

Comment: I found a dirty fix: after running `ps -ef | grep dpkg`, I found that this was running : `/bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/minergate-cli.postinst configure`. So I deleted the `.postinst` file, and killed the command again. The next time I ran ` dpkg --configure -a`, it ended immediatly after starting `Setting up minergate-cli (4.05) ...`. 
Was there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1.you coud download .deb file from https://minergate.com/download/deb-cli ,then uncompress it, upload the 'minergate' folder to the linux, execute the ./minergate-cli script to start, no need to install.

2. check your http connection to Internet, it means the http connection between your linux and Minergate is not ok.